# selecting dropdown value in coldfusion using jquery

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have 3 dropdowns `DD1`, `DD2` and `DD3` in the header section in which the values are populated using ColdFusion and jQuery. Also I have another dropdown named `'Main'` which is having the values `DD1`, `DD2` and `DD3`. Means the dropdowns in the header section form the values of the Main dropdown.

Assume I selected some values for header dropdowns `DD1`, `DD2` and `DD3` dropdowns. Also the value `DD2` from the Main dropdown. Now the **problem** I am facing is: If I select `DD2` from Main, I want to get that value from the header dropdown `DD2`, which is currently selected (means if in `DD2` I selected mango, when I select `DD2` from the Main dropdown, mango should be alerted).

Below is the code snippet I am trying to do
`build_dd` is used to construct the header dropdowns `DD1`, `DD2` and `DD3`

```
<cfloop query="build_dd">
       <cfoutput>#build_dd.value#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I tried the below line. But this gave me selected values of DD1, DD2 and DD3. I want only that which is selected in Main

```
 alert("selectedindex "+jQuery("select[name='<cfoutput>#build_dd.value#</cfoutput>'] option:selected").text());
```

Could some body please help me on this

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Just give the select boxes id's, like dd1 or whatever. Then you can just use `$('#dd1').val();`

Bonus: if you make the options of your "main" the IDs of DD1, DD2, DD3, you can make this really easily.

```
<select id="main">
   <option value="dd1">DD1</option>
   <option value="dd2">DD2</option>
   <option value="dd3">DD3</option>
</select>
```

then your JS is super simple

```
$('#main').change(function(){
   alert($('#'+$('#main').val()).val());
});
```